# Elasticsearch hide attribute tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

The results sent by the elasticsearch contain attributes generic to Elasticsearch.
Example of a JSON returned by rails server.

```
{

 locality_name: "some text",
 locality_details: "some text",

 _score: null,
 _type: "locality",
 _index: "localities",
 _version: null,
 sort: [
 1.0860322703674736
 ],
 highlight: null,
 _explanation: null
 }
```

As you can observe,the major content of the result being transferred is occupied by default attributes of Elasticsearch such as _score,_sort,_explanation.

I believe suppressing this behaviour will result in lower size of the JSON object being returned in the result and hence improvement in performance. Does elasticsearch provide such functionality?
Also how does Tire incorporate that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is the `fields` parameter: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/fields/

Comment: I have a fields parameter in my search method but I think it defaults to load the internal _source field of elasticsearch.

Comment: yeah, that's where you define which fields to return instead of `_source`

Comment: in `tire.search` method i have included `fields["attr1","attr2"]`,and all which I need in the result]`.How do I exclude attributes of elasticsearch in fields?

Comment: it does not look like that you can disable this metadata: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/17BAQsENCBI i don't think that it will make any difference in terms of throughput in any case.

Comment: yeah..did not find any such documentation yet

Comment: I think `_source` attribute can be hidden through enabled:false but I'm not sure of this property working for _sort,_score attributes.